# ASP.NET MySQL ConnectionString error "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
Source Error (Line 26): 


Line 24: 
Line 25:             conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
**Line 26:             conn.Open();**
Line 27:             queryStr = "";
Line 28:
```

My connection string is:

```
   <connectionStrings>
        <add name="webAppConnString"
        connectionString="Server=mysql6.000webhost.com; Uid=a2867246_root; Pwd=******; Database=a2867246_canvas;"
        providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

It works fine with localhost(127.0.0.1) but when I try to use remote MySQL server, it fails to connect. Error log:

```
[MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +413
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() +75
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +268
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() +44
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +368
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() +199
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +125
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +1105
   WebApplication5.Default.submitEventMethod(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\****\WebApplication5\Default.aspx.cs:26
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9633690
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: Check the server firewall and the a2867246_root permission, whether it is a @ or %. Easiest way is to use an MySQL client to connect from your PC to the server with the user and password. From the message, it looks more like the firewall.

Comment: [C# Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com) check this out for how to configure your database if that doesn't help google how to configure your database to use namedpipes

Comment: Never post your connection string passwords on a public site like this... even if it is just a test enviro

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this myself as well as other developers I know.

One of the easy fixes (standard procedures to do at the beginning) is to **put all of the parameters in the correct** order such as this:

```
Server=TheServerAddress; Port=YourPortNumber; Database=YourDatabase; Uid=YourUsername; Pwd=YourPassword;
```

In your particular case it should look like this:

```
Server=mysql6.000webhost.com; Database=a2867246_canvas; Uid=a2867246_root; Pwd=1234pass1234;
```